# Java error: cannot find symbol list.addPerson(p);

Tags: java, symbols

I'm getting an error that I don't understand. I'm totally new to java and my naming convention is probably terrible.

Can someone please help me understand why this error is occurring and how can I fix it ?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class prj2
{
   public static void main (String[] args)
   {
      Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
      List list = new List();
      while (scan.hasNext())
      {
         String first = scan.next();
         String last = scan.next();
         int zip = scan.nextInt();
         Person p = new Person(first,last,zip);
         list.addPerson(p); //THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR IS OCCURING
      }
   System.out.println(list);
   }
}
```

Comment: please post the error message

Comment: `list.addPerson(p);` ?? Have you created class `List` or using `java.util.List` ?

Comment: Please post your person class and the error message

Answer (score 1):

The code is missing import statement for List and Person classes.

Please confirm if List is a custom class. If not, you may change the declaration of list as follows.

List list = new ArrayList();

Note: Explicit import is not required if the classes are in same package.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create a `List` you need to create a type of list like `arraylist`

Comment: *You cannot create a List*.. No he can If he has created class `List`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have three errors:

- You cannot use a data structure before you import it.
- You cannot instantiate an interface, such as `List`.
- You should assign a type to `List`

To fix the first error, import `java.util.ArrayList` and `java.util.List`.

To fix the remaining two errors, change line 7 from `List list = new List();` to `List<Person> list = new ArrayList<>();`.

Check out the [Java Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) on `List`.